# mongoose: validation error on post request

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to save a new use in mongodb with mongoose, but I am getting ValidationError:  "err": "User validation failed:Path 'email' is required., Path 'fname' is required., Path 'username' is required  phone: Path `phone` .despite I make all the data in the body of the post request so:

this is the userModel:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {type: Number},
name: {type: String, required: true},
fname: {type: String, required: true},
phone: {type: String, required: true},
email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
password: {type: String, required: false},
image: {type: String, required: false},
isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false, required: true},
}, {
    timeStamps: true
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
export default User;
```

this is the userRouter.js:

```
import express from "express";
import data from '../../data.js';
import User from "../userModel.js";
import expressAsyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import {generateToken} from "../../utils.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";


const userRouter = express.Router();
let allUsers = data.users;
userRouter.get("/seed", expressAsyncHandler(async(req, res)=>{
  //await User.remove({});
   const createdUsers = await User.insertMany(allUsers);
   res.send({createdUsers});
}));
userRouter.post("/register", expressAsyncHandler(async(req, res)=> {
 //await User.remove({});


const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    fname: req.body.fname,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    email: req.body.email,
    
  });

  const createdUser = await user.save();
 res.send({
   _id: createdUser._id,
   name: createdUser.name,
   fname: createdUser.fname,
   phone: createdUser.phone,
   email: createdUser.email,
  
   token: generateToken(createdUser)

 })
}))





export default userRouter;
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant frontend code?

Comment: just i try this code with postman

Comment: And the code where you set up the server, it's probably an express config problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the properties exist in `req.body`?

Comment: postman is an assimalation of this you could make the body of your request in the post request

Comment: Add a `console.log(req.body)` before calling `user.save()`

Comment: you are right my friend it render empty object

Comment: i maked all my code as you see